# Determine which keys should 2 tables use to Join in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have the follwoing 2 Tables:

Table1:

```
User-ID    Country

1111    USA 
2222    Brazil
3331    USA
3332    Korea
3333    Korea
3333    USA
3333    France
4444    UK
```

Table2:

```
User-ID   Country  Region

1111      USA       NA
2222      Brazil    SA
3331      Korea     A
3332      Korea     A
3333      N/A       N/A
3330      France    E
4444      UK        E
```

I would like to join both table using the 'User-ID' as the common key with an exception.

What I want the result to be like is that when the User-ID is '3333' I would like the 'Country' to be the common key instead ONLY.

I have tried the following ncode which sounded logical per my understanding but did not return the desitred result:

```
Select T1.User-ID, T1.Country, Case When T1.User-ID ='3333' AND T1.Country = 
       T2.Country THEN T2.Region ELSE T2.Region END

From Table1 as T1 Left Outer Join
     Table2 as T2 ON T1.User-ID = T2.User-ID OR T1.Country = T2.Country
```

I have tried few other approaches buty with no succes, the results I will get will be the following:

- NULL Region for User-ID 3333
- Dublicated rows for USer-ID 3333
  While the records other than 3333 will return expected outcomes.

Comment: `THEN T2.Region ELSE T2.Region END` So why you are using `CASE` expression since in both cases it will return `T2.Region` value? or it's just a typo?

Comment: @Sami that was an unnecessary code that I forgot to remove after changing my conditions, missed it because it didn't affect the result. Thank you : )

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want an additional condition in the `ON` clause:

```
From Table1 T1 Left Outer Join
     Table2 T2
     ON T1.UserID = T2.UserID AND
        (T1.UserId <> 33333 OR T1.Country = T2.Country)
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, I guess I've described the tables in my questions incorrectly. I have editted it. I've produced a fiddle here to make it clear [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c3a58/1)